# Send mail from Gsuite mail alias with PHPMailer

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer, google-apps

I'm trying to use PHPMailer on my website to send mail as part of a contact form. I would like to use `contact@example.com` instead of `standard_email@example.com` to send mail, for filtering and security. My mail is handled by GSuite (formerly called Google Apps) and is setup like below:

- **User** - `standard_email@example.com`
- ***Alias*** - `contact@example.com  -->  standard_email@example.com`

I have sending working perfectly when using `standard_email@example.com` in the PHPMailer configuration, but when I try to send using the alias it does not work. Is this not possible with GSuite aliases?

### Contact Controller

```
define("SMTP_HOST", "smtp.gmail.com");
define("MAIL_ADDRESS", "alias@example.com");
define("SMTP_USERNAME", "alias@example.com");
...

//Configure SMTP authentication
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = SMTP_HOST;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = SMTP_USERNAME;
$mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;

//Set email headers
$mail->setFrom(MAIL_ADDRESS, "Contact Us Submission");
$mail->addAddress(MAIL_ADDRESS, "Contact Us Submission");
$mail->addReplyTo($form_email, $form_name);
$mail->isHTML(true);

//Set email content
$mail->Subject = htmlspecialchars($form_subject);
$mail->Body = htmlspecialchars($form_comments);
$mail->AltBody = htmlspecialchars($form_comments);

//Attempt to send the message and display the results to the user
if ($mail->send() == false) {
    return new MailResponse(1, "Message could not be sent", $contactSubmission);
} else {
    return new MailResponse(0, "Message sent successfully", $contactSubmission);
}
```

I've also tried using `standard_email@example.com` as the `SMTP_USERNAME` and `alias@example.com` as the `MAIL_ADDRESS`, but that didn't work either.

### Results

There are no reported errors, and the page displays the "success" mail message; however, no mail is actually sent/received when I visit my user. Since GSuite apparently routes all of the alias mail to my standard address, I should be seeing it.

Let me know if I'm missing something, and thanks!

Comment: If you set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` you can watch the SMTP conversation and see if there's anything interesting in there. Separate thing: you shouldn't be calling `htmlspecialchars` on `AltBody` or `Subject` - it's not treated as HTML in those, so if anything you should be calling `strip_tags`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I will definitely change the `htmlspecialchars` references. As far as the `SMTPDebug` goes, I had it set to Level 3 and didn't notice anything out of the ordinary, which is what bothered me. I'll try it again and post the output (maybe of both).

Comment: Gmail's usual thing is that it just silently changes the from address to the account address if you try to use something else. I have seen aliases work though.

Comment: @Synchro how did they get aliases to work?

Comment: You have to define aliases in your gmail settings; once you've done that you can use them as from addresses.

Answer (score 2):

The solution from @Synchro works and for convenience here is a short step by step solution:

1. On your computer, open Gmail.
2. In the top right, click Settings Settings and then See all settings.
3. Click the Accounts and import or Accounts tab.
4. In the "Send mail as" section, click Add another email address.
5. Enter your name and the address you want to send from.
6. Click Next Step and then Send verification.
7. Click Add Account

Learn more: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Everything should be working now :)